# Androidビルド環境構築時のgoogle play service

Tags: android, build, google-play-service

今まで、eclipseでコーディングからビルドまで行っていたのですが、
今回、CentOSにてJenkinsビルド環境を構築中です。
作成しているアプリで、google play serviceを使用しているので
[Referencing a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)を行ったのですが、

```
/usr/lib/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project
```

が出て、BUILD FAILEDになります。 
解決策を教えてください。 よろしくお願いします。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265111/android-ant-build-fails-with-google-play-services-lib-resolve-to-a-path-with
によれば、絶対パスではなく相対パスで試してみてとのこと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事通りました。（また、別のエラーが出てしまったですがｗ）こないだその記事みたんですが、意図が汲み取れてなかったようです。どおりで、eclipseのproject.propertiesも相対パスになってるわけですね。納得です。相対パスって・・・。/まで戻るのに・・・。ありがとうございました！

Comment: せっかくですから、コメントではなくてちゃんとした回答を付けて accept しませんか?

Comment: ごめんなさい、使い方がよくわかってないです。

Comment: なるほど。一覧で見ると「0回答」になってるわけですね。

Answer (score 1):

[Referencing a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)の注意です。

```
android update project --target <target_ID> --path path/to/your/project --library path/to/library_projectA
```

--library path/to/library_projectAのpathの部分は絶対パスではなく相対パスにしないと  
ビルドエラーになります。

project.properties内に記述する場合も同じで、

```
android.library.reference.1=path/to/library_projectA
```

pathの部分は絶対パスではなく相対パスにしないとビルドエラーになります。

[user2904](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/2904/user2904)さん、ありがとうございました。